# Is it possible to disable the cursor from being recorded with getDisplayMedia()

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

I am recording my browser window using MediaStream and MediaRecorder.

But need to disable the mouse cursor from being recorded, so when I create my video track, i use the following code:

```
stream['input'] = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: {
    cursor: 'never',
    frameRate: 40,
}
});
console.log( stream['input'].getVideoTracks()[0].getSettings() );
```

However chrome, opera and edge console displays:

```
aspectRatio: 1.7777777777777777
cursor: "motion"
deviceId: "window:200730:1"
displaySurface: "window"
frameRate: 40
height: 1080
logicalSurface: true
resizeMode: "crop-and-scale"
width: 1920
```

But seem to ignore the setting, so the cursor is being recorded.

I can see the frameRate constraint is being set in my console, however I just cannot for the life of me seem to disable the cursor.

Yet, firefox doesn't record the cursor and shows this in the console

```
frameRate: 40
​height: 924
​width: 1263
```

Has anyone successfully managed to disable the cursor at all with Chrome, Edge and Opera?

i've even tried using

```
stream['input'].getVideoTracks()[0].applyConstraints( { 
video: { cursor: 'never', frameRate: 30 } 
} );
```

Which doesn't work :-(

Update:
I can see from the chart here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints

that the cursor constraint is only supposed to be supported on opera.  However the output from getSupportedConstraints() shows cursor is not supported after all.

Thanks

Comment: It's called `getDisplayMedia()`. You may get better answers if you [edit] your question to correct the name.

Comment: lol, thx.  i was in blurry eyes mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the bottom of this page you'll find a table showing browser support for various `MediaTrackConstraints' properties.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackSupportedConstraints

`cursor` isn't widely supported, sad to say.

You can use `getSupportedConstraints()` to find out what is supported in the browser where your code is running.

Try this in your devtools console to see what your browser can or more likely, can't, do.

```js
console.log(navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints())
```

Comment: "You're in a maze of twisty little passages, all different." Figuring this stuff out is a pain in the xxx neck. Don't give up!

Comment: Hi, I did that and it looks like cursor isn't supported.  What i don't get is with chrome, edge and opera the cursor constraint changes automatically from "motion" to "always".  Yet the API says it can be changed to "motion", "always" or "never".  And the fact that you can see them with getSettings() doesnt make sense.

Comment: I feel your pain! These APIs on the fringes of WebRTC are chaotic right now. And the whole idea of constraint objects would make for a confusing API even if everything worked as advertised. The docs on MDN usually reflect the W3C's specs, translated from W3C's abstract specification language to Javascript API descriptions. In that they represent an ideal, a target, and sometimes even the reality of the implementations. In other words, the stuff on MDN might be bul*** -- might not be right.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't always work to hide the cursor using the getDisplayMedia() function options.

```
const captureOptions = {
video: {
      cursor: "hidden"
      }
};
navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(captureOptions);
```

The 100% functional way is to hide the cursor before capturing.
Then, after the capture, we return to the original or 'default' cursor

```
const bodyElement = document.querySelector('body');
bodyElement.style.cursor = 'none';
```