# How to disable / hide the mouse cursor to be recorded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, mediarecorder, web-mediarecorder

I want to record the screen of the user, but I want to hide / exclude the cursor to be recorded. I researched about this and found out this article :-

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackSettings/cursor

The above can be used to disable the mouse to be recorded from the recording and in the official documents it is mentioned cursor as a available values :-
[image]

I am not sure where and how to use the above parameter to disable or hide the mouse cursor. I am using tabCapture api which basically is like getUserDisplay :-

```js
chrome.tabCapture.capture({ 
     video: true,
     audio: false,
     videoConstraints:{
                  
     mandatory:
          {cursor: 'never', minFrameRate:70,maxFrameRate:120,maxWidth:1920,maxHeight:1080}} 
              
          }
```

I used the cursor parameter like above, but it didn't work, the cursor still showing up in the recording,
It would be a great help if you please show a small demo for the recording of the screen but excluding the cursor

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question? > Help others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I am not sure what to include in the above question, its not an error or something, its just a question of how this could be done

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, but it seems like according to the docs, your way of adding the `cursor` property is correct, it's just that the browser probably doesn't support it yet, you can try executing this statement in your browser console to see if `cursor` property is supported: `navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints()`

Comment: @Damzaky, I did, it seems that it won't show the cursor property

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64253711/3085642) answer

**cursor** property is not widely supported!

Instead you can use `getSupportedConstraints()` to find out what is supported in the browser where your code is running.

Try this in your devtools console to see what your browser can or more likely, can't, do.

```js
console.log(navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints())
```

then from the result list you can add use necessary properties to hide/make invisible the cursor.